# How to add banner comments on sublime text using Julia

Tags: sublimetext3, comments

I am trying to mark my code with banner comment/ decorated ASCII text that would be configured so that they are visible from the minimap, like [this](https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/asci-banners-in-minimap-from-single-line-comment/13492). 
I tried [this](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/CommentBanner) but cannot get it to work.

Does anyone have a solution please?

Thanks

Comment: What does this have to do with Julia? Can you use Julia to write Sublime plugins or something?

Comment: The plugin you linked to doesn't do what was illustrated in that forum post, it simply surrounds some text in a box. Please [edit] your question and add greater detail about what exactly you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to be such a noob, I realised I had a lack of vocabulary to search and actually there is already an answer. I do not know if I should delete my question or not, but here is the solution:

There is an [ASCII decorator package](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/ASCII%20Decorator) on sublime text allowing to do that.

To be sure that the text selectred appears as a comment, I went to Preferences > Browse Package > ascii decorator > ASCII Decorator.sublime-settings and changed the comment value to true. The same file allows to change the default font.

The result is attached - using the font Georgia11 [image]